# How to use the same EntityListBuilder for entity A and an extended version B

Tags: 8, views

I have used the [content entity example](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/content_entity_example!content_entity_example.module/group/content_entity_example/8.x-1.x) coming from the [example project](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples).

This example define a Contact entity.

Next I have extended this Contact class in an Artist class with some added fields (let say a Bio and a Cv field).

```
class Artist extends Contact  {
```

My Idea was to share the list_builder defined in the Contact class in order to get an administrative list showing the Contacts and the Artists at the same place.

To do so, I have those annotations in the **Artist** class:

```
 * @ContentEntityType(
  * id = "mymodule_artist",
  * label = @Translation("Artist entity"),
  * handlers = {
  * "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
  * "list_builder" = "Drupal\mymodule\Entity\Controller\ContactListBuilder",
  * ...
```

As you can see, **ContactListBuilder** is the list builder of the Contact entity... in other words, it is used in Contact and in Artist.

In the routing.yml I have the following

```
entity.mymodule_artist.collection:
  path: '/mymodule_contact/list'
  defaults:
    _entity_list: 'mymodule_contact'
    _title: 'Contact List'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'view contact entity'
```

Unfortunately, this is not working at all... the ContactListBuilder shows only the Contact entities; not the Artists. (I couldn't understand why)

After many tries, I drop this idea... My new plan was now to create a view that will show all Contacts and all Artists.

Thus, I added this line in the annotations of the Contact and the Artist classes (in the "handlers" section):

```
 * "views_data" = "Drupal\mymodule\ContactViewsData",
```

And here is my **ContactViewsData** class definition

```
class ContactViewsData extends EntityViewsData  {
}
```

As you can see it is empty: it only extends EntityViewsData. In fact I really don't understand what to do in the `getViewsData()` function. I couldn't find any doc on it (But this is maybe something I should ask in another question)

Anyway, this does the job, and I could create a view (in the UI) for the Contacts and another view for the Artists. But I have no clue on how to create a view that are showing both.

To summarize, my questions are:

1. Is extending the Contact class (for the Artists) a good idea? Maybe it is much simpler to just add the Artist's fields in the Contact Class.
2. What is the best way to list a Mix of 2 entities that are sharing some common fields (Ex: Name, Surname, ID,...): Is it a view?
3. Is it a good Idea to try to use the same ListBuilder for 2 entities (Of course, this Listbuilder will only list the common fields)
4. Where to find some doc on the getViewsData()` function, or at least, what is the purpose of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions cover quite a few unrelated concepts, but here's an attempt at answering nonetheless.

1. **Create a 'Person' base class** and extend that into 'Contact' and 'Artist' classes. This approach will isolate your Artist entity type form changes you need to make to the Contact class and vice versa. Adding a company-field would, as an example, probably not apply to your artists.
2. I would use a **content-view with a filter**, only showing *contacts* and *artists* types. Re-using common fields on the 2 entities will make creating such a view a no-brainer.
3. Afaik the parent list-builder class does not support multiple entity types. The constructor for the list-builder class, accepts *$entity_type* as one of its arguments, so unless you write your own list-builder, you are limited to **1 type per list**.
4. The getViewsData() method exposes properties from your entity type to the [views api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/group/views_overview/8.4.x). Extending the EntityViewsData class, like you did, auto-generates the view-data through the inherited methods. Core provides some usage examples; e.g. [UserViewsData](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserViewsData.php/class/UserViewsData/8.4.x). Use your IDE to search for "extends getViewsData()" for more examples.